# Proper way of accessing the $scope within ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-view

Here is my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/j4DKvePwtL2kSL0Pmnrt?p=preview).

I am using `ngRoute`.

I am trying to increment a value by `ng-click`, and when I click "Show total" link, it should load the `ng-view` template showing the value. However, it does not show the incremented value. It's like it's not accessing the scope.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `MainCtrl` controller from your $routeProvider when condition, which is loading `MainCtrl` again, and unnecessary scope has been created.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/total',{
    templateUrl : 'template.html',
    //controller : 'MainCtrl' //<-- remove controller here
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're resetting the value of `$scope.total` when it lands on the `/total` route. ng-init can be used to initialize the value of total outside of the controller